# Function is only reading highest value swift

Tags: swift

I am working on this project right now and the goal is to have three buttons, for three different difficulties, that segues to a new ViewController based on which button was pressed. No matter which button I press, it defaults to the hardest mode.

I was thinking that it would be possible to fix it if I was able to use the buttons as outlets but Xcode is only letting me use them as actions, which wouldn't help my case.

```
import UIKit

class numberViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var difficulty = String()
    var buttonMessage: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        buttonAction()
        stackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 3500)
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 3500)
    }
    func checkDifficulty() -> Int{
        if difficulty == "easy" {
            return 15
        }
        else if difficulty == "medium"{
            return 45
        }
        else{
            return 105
        }
    }

    @objc func tooLow(sender: UIButton!){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again!", message: "Too low!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
    @objc func tooHigh(sender: UIButton!){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Try again!", message: "Too high!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
    @objc func justRight(sender: UIButton!){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congrats! You got it!", message: "Go back and try a harder level.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
    @objc func buttonAction() {
        var number = Int.random(in: 1...checkDifficulty())
        let buttons = (1...checkDifficulty()).map({ (x) -> UIButton in
            let newButton = UIButton()
            newButton.setTitle("Button \(x)", for: .normal)
            newButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 25)
            newButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0.3, green: 0.5, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1)
            if x < number {
                newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tooLow), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            else if x > number {
                newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tooHigh), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            else{
                newButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(justRight), for: .touchUpInside)
            }
            return newButton
        })
        for button in buttons{
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
            let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: button, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttons[0], attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

            if button != buttons[0] {
                stackView.addConstraint(constraint)

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Anything you could think of would help tremendously.

FIXED: Forgot to use prepare for segue to determine what difficulty the player wanted.

Comment: better way to deal with `Enum` instead of taking level as string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are saying

```
var difficulty = String()
```

So now `difficulty` is `""`, the empty string. And *you never change it*. So when the time comes to check its value:

```
func checkDifficulty() -> Int{
    if difficulty == "easy" {
        return 15
    }
    else if difficulty == "medium"{
        return 45
    }
    else{
        return 105
    }
}
```

You get the final `else` case, because `difficulty` is still `""`. It is not `"easy"` or `"medium"` because *you* never *set* it to either of those.

Comment: Ahh, that makes some sense. Thank you